# How can I automatically overwrite a wrapped line?

Tags: spacing, line-spacing, vspace

This is probably the opposite of what most people are going for but I'd like to let the text of my lines overwrite themselves. As an example, if I have:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
These are some words that I'd like to overwrite when they wrap instead of just
continuing onto the next line like they should for a regular document. 
\end{document}
```

This will wrap across two lines as you would expect. I can achieve what I'm looking for with something like:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
These are some words that I'd like to overwrite when they wrap instead of\par
\vspace{-1.2em}
just continuing onto the next line like they should for a regular document. 
\end{document}
```

But I was wondering if there was something I could redefine or set such that when the line wraps, it doesn't advance down the page at all. I could of course manually edit the blocks with breaks and negative vspace but I was hoping to do something a bit more elegantly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

baselineskip set to 0pt

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\setlength\baselineskip{0pt}
\setlength\lineskiplimit{-\maxdimen}

These are some words that I'd like to overwrite when they wrap instead of just
continuing onto the next line like they should for a regular document. 
\end{document}
```

Comment: That does seem to work in isolation, I must have some sort of conflict; it doesn't do anything in my full document. I was able to work around this with a minipage, thanks!

Comment: @user1794469 `\baselineskip` is reset by any font size command, including `\normalsize` which is used in any number of places, so such a declaration can only be used in a controlled environment when other things are not undoing it

Comment: Thanks for the followup. This worked: `\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
\setlength\baselineskip{0pt}
\setlength\lineskiplimit{-\maxdimen}
{\fontsize{1}{1}\selectfont ... } \end{minipage}` but not without the minipage.